なぜneverをreturnできない？
function hoge(message: string): null {
  return null;
}

nullは上記のように書けて、
function hoge(message: string): never {
  return never;
}

neverでは駄目なのでしょうか？ もちろん、neverは下記のような用途と理解しています。
function hoge(message: string): never {
  throw new Error();
}

下記のように 1 といった他の言語ではみたこともないようなものさえ返り値の型として使用できるのに、neverだけ（他にもあるかもですが）、できないのは、不思議です。
function hoge(message: string): 1 {
  return 1;
}

特に解決したい問題がなく、単なる疑問なので、もしかするとStackOverflow向きではないかもしれません。

never 型はそこに到達不可能であることを示す型です。never 型の値は存在しないので、ある関数が何かしら値を返しているのにその関数の返り値の型が never であると、型検査でエラーになります。
null 型や、リテラル型のひとつである 1 型は、never 型とは異なります。null 型の値として null があるので、関数が null を返し、その返り値の型が null のとき型検査は通ります。1 型の場合も同様です。
より詳しい解説：never -- TypeScript Deep Dive 日本語版
